# Is (X x X) x Y considered a Cartesian Product of three sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am very new to discrete mathematics and I was shown the following question as a preview question for a coming quiz, our textbook however never touched on such scenario so I am quite lost.

let X = {a} and Y = {a, b}

find (X x X) x Y

Would (X x X) x Y be {(a, a, a), (a, a, b)} ?

I'm very lost about what you can do with a set of ordered pairs. Sorry if this is a really stupid question, I tried searching for similar questions on the internet but all I could find were simple examples of X x Y and such.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: X x X x Y (without parenthesis) is {(a, a, a), (a, a, b)} but (X x X) x Y = {((a, a), a), ((a, a), b)}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the cartesian product is the following:
Let $M$ and $N$ be sets, then
\begin{equation*}
M \times N = \{(m,n)\mid m \in M \ \ \text{and} \ \ n \in N\}.
\end{equation*}

In your question $X = \{a\}$ and $Y = \{a,b\}$ and we are asked to provide
$(X \times X)\times Y$. First let's look at the bracket. Since $X$ only has one element:
\begin{equation*}
X \times X = \{(a,a)\}.
\end{equation*}
Now per definition
\begin{equation*}
(X \times X)\times Y = \{(x,y)\mid x \in X\times X \ \ \text{and} \ \ y \in Y\},
\end{equation*}
therefore
\begin{equation*}
(X \times X)\times Y = \{((a,a),a),((a,a),b)\}.
\end{equation*}